# How to define a numeric variable?

Tags: macros

Following the [Latex wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros) I tried `\newcommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\marginProportion}{0.76}   
\usepackage[scale=\marginProportion{}]{geometry} 

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Both of which cause a myriad of compilation errors.

Comment: `scale=\marginProportion` should work, but not `scale=\marginProportion{}`. `\DeclareRobustCommand` does not work since it's not expandable

Comment: The key-value syntax does not expand the key value `\marginProportion`, just copies content and in the case of `\marginProporption{}` it adds content to the value which shouldn't be there (the `{}` pair)

Comment: It has to be added, from my point of view, that the `{}` issue is actually not limited to a 'numerical' variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Key-value approaches (often) do not expand the key values.

In this case `scale=\marginProportion{}` will just be copied, as can be shown from the verbatim output of `\typeout` of the `dummykey` definition. The second call with trailing `{}` will just have those `{}` as key value, conflicting with the expected input for the `scale` key from `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{fam}{dummykey}{%
  \def\FamKVMacroDummy{#1}
  \typeout{#1}
}%

\makeatother


\newcommand{\somecmd}[1]{%
  \setkeys{fam}{#1}
Printing the key value:  \FamKVMacroDummy
}

\newcommand{\marginProportion}{0.76}
\usepackage[scale=\marginProportion]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\somecmd{dummykey=\marginProportion}

\somecmd{dummykey=\marginProportion{}}

\end{document}
```

---

---

```
./numvar.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
0.76
0.76{}
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./numvar.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on numvar.pdf (1 page, 13994 bytes).
Transcript written on numvar.log.
```

`\DeclareRobustCommand` will not expand to `0.76` so this is useless here, as well as `\newrobustcmd` from `etoolbox`.

Comment: Such a great answer! Also, thank you for showing me that "debugging" technique!